# Get key value from array of dictionaries if you know another key value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of dictionaries :

```
var elements = [{ "COLOR" : "RED", "NAME" : "R1"},{"COLOR" : "BLUE", "NAME" :"R2"}, and so on ]
```

From this array first i need to create another array with only the name values.
It look like this :

```
var names = ["R1", "R2"]
```

After that i loop through it and check if another array contains the element from the names array:

```
for (var name in names){
    if (array2.includes(names[name])){

array2 = ["R1", "RT", "RG" ....]
```

If the condition is true i want to show a message.
My question is how do i get the color value if i know the name value.

Ex: `console.log("NAME is " +  names[name] + " and color for that name is" + ???`

So for R1 the message should look like this :
NAME IS R1 and color for that name is RED.

Comment: `elements[name].COLOR` for the colour and `elements[name].NAME` for the name

Comment: What does `array2` look like? Does it have the same object references as `elements` array? Otherwise, `includes` will never be true.

Comment: What is `array2`? Use `for..of` instead of `for..in` for arrays to directly access the values in the array

Comment: @adiga I edited the post because i forgot something.  array2 looks like this = ["R3", "42", "R1", "R2"]

Comment: Please update  the question.

Comment: @ adiga I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var array2 = ["R1", "RT", "RG"]
var elements = [{
  "COLOR": "RED",
  "NAME": "R1"
}, {
  "COLOR": "BLUE",
  "NAME": "R2"
}]

var names = ["R1", "R2"]


for (var name in names) {
  if (array2.includes(names[name])) {
    const matchName = elements.find(element => element.NAME === names[name]);
    console.log("NAME is " + matchName.NAME + " color for that name is " + matchName.COLOR)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elements = [{ "COLOR" : "RED", "NAME" : "R1"},{"COLOR" : "BLUE", "NAME" :"R2"}]
const names = ["R1", "R2"]

names.forEach(name => 
  console.log(name, ":", elements.find(x => x["NAME"] === name)["COLOR"])
)
```